# how to update embeded document in mongodb using C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, c#-4.0, mongodb-.net-driver

i have one collection in which i  am doing insert/update operation. for insert i use the     code:

```
MongoCollection<BsonDocument> tblCity = mydb.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("tblCity");
BsonDocument CollectionCity = new BsonDocument {
                    { "CityCode", cityCode },
                    { "CityName", cityName },
                    { "stamps" , new BsonDocument { 
                        {"ins", DateTime.Now}, 
                        {"upd", ""}, 
                        {"createUsr", UserId}, 
                        {"updUsr", ""}, 
                        {"Ins_Ip", ""},
                        {"Upd_IP", GetIP()}
                        }
                    }
                };
        tblCity.Insert(CollectionCity);
```

it is working fine. but while i am updating  i am using code:

```
MongoCollection <BsonDocument>  tblCity = mydb.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("tblCity"); 
var query = new QueryDocument { { "City_strCode", cityCode } };
var update = new UpdateDocument {
     { "$set", new BsonDocument("City_strName", cityName) },
     { "stamps" , new BsonDocument{
         {"upd",  DateTime.Now}, 
         {"updUsr", ""}, 
         {"Upd_IP", GetIP()
     }}
}};

tblCity.Update(query, update);
```

But problem is that with out changing the `ins` date i want to update `upd` field. But it is removing the `ins` field and updating the `upd` field. I am trying a lot of ways but not able to get any solution. Please suggest something....Even I got some links based on this and tried.. but none of them workout.

Comment: Have you tried using the dot (.) notation? For example: `"stamps.upd"`? Your existing code is overwriting the entire `stamps` field with a new document.

Comment: @WiredPrairie: ya i tried same "stamps.upd" but it is consider this as a separate field. "stamps.upd" is work directly in mongo shell but in C# code it is not working

Comment: @WiredPrairie: Thanks Yaar Bellow code working fin... thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to fix your use of `$set` and the query.

Your query doesn't match with the field name in the inserted document.

```
var query = new QueryDocument { { "CityCode", cityCode  } };
```

If you're using `$set`, then pass all of the fields you want to change as part of the `BsonDocument`:

```
var query = new QueryDocument { { "CityCode", cityCode  } };
var update = new UpdateDocument {
        { "$set", new BsonDocument {
        { "CityName", "San Fran"}, 
        { "stamps.upd" , DateTime.Now()}, 
        { "stamps.updUsr", ""}, 
        { "stamps.Upd_IP", "10.0.0.1" }
}}};
```